# Horizontal "bars" instead of video when recording with MediaRecorder

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

Subject A: Horizontal Bars

[image: Horizontal Bars on Video]

This is a weird one.  The video records and the sound is fine, but those bars represent my hand.  It is as if I am looking a ribbed pyrex bowl:

Subject B:

[image: Ribbed Pyrex Bowl]

I am testing this on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 using the **front facing** camera (API 16).  Some notes:

- When I record using the **back facing** camera, it records fine.
- When I record using the front facing camera in the standard camera
  app, it works fine.
- When I run the same code on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (API 21),
  both back and front cameras work fine.

I use `CamcorderProfile` to select the appropriate `MediaRecorder` settings.  Here is my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {
    // Get screen width and height for supported video sizes
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width, height;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
        width = display.getWidth();
        height = display.getHeight();
    } else {
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
    }

    // Check and set the highest quality available recording profile of the camera.
    int frontCamera = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    CamcorderProfile profile = null;

    if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P))
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
    else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P))
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
    else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P))
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
    else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH))
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(frontCamera, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    mCamera = CameraHelper.getDefaultFrontFacingCameraInstance();

    // Need to make sure that our recording video size is supported by the camera.
    // Query camera to find all sizes and choose the optimal size given the dimensions of screen.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> mSupportedVideoSizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
    Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalRecordingSize(mSupportedVideoSizes,
            width, height);

    // link camera to preview surface
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Surface text is unavailable or unsuitable for preview" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    // Unlock the camera to allow the Media Recorder to own it
    mCamera.unlock();

    // Create and assign the Camera to the Media Recorder
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Set Sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    if (profile != null) {
        profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
        profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
    }

    // Specify the output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
            CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've tried bypassing the `CamcorderProfile` and trying [every `MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder` encoder available](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html).  The file format is .mp4, which I don't believe is the issue because the standard Camera app on the device outputs a .mp4.  Any ideas?